# Admob rewarded video ads not fill

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

i was using only Google admob, i added adcolony plugin my application, and my google reward ads would not run 3 days later. I downloaded all google's shared codes, plugins and projects. Still it is not working, what should I do? I was watching ads videos in my application last week. Thank u.

I removed all adcolony plugins, codes and Mediation. Still it is not working. Already i downloaded AdMob Rewarded Video Example (Java) in https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/tag/5.3

I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3